# Does FreeBSD contain non-free software in its base?

Tags: freebsd, bsd, licenses, open-source

I mean binary blobs compiled by third parties. Additionally if you do pkg install, are there non-free packages considered by default?

Comment: Yes, there are mostly firmware blobs by default.

Comment: I think not in the kernel, but I cannot find a good link for that.

Comment: Debian GNU/kFreeBSD could be the answer if you're looking for completely free OS with BSD kernel.

Answer (score 4):

Of course it does, otherwise lots of basic hardware (i.e. network adapters) wouldn't work.  Most of it — everything apart from two HighPoint drivers — is microcode.

There is a mechanism to build the kernel without it — just define `WITHOUT_SOURCELESS` in `/etc/src.conf` and rebuild the kernel and world.  As usual, it's all documented in the [manual page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?src.conf)